# Remove parent and all it's children from already fetched collection

Tags: laravel

Here is what my table looks like:

```
Cars:
+-------+---------+---------+
| Type  |  Name   |  Brand  |
+-------+---------+---------+
| brand | BMW     | null    |
| brand | Audi    | null    |
| model | X3      | BMW     |
| model | A4      | Audi    |
| model | Picasso | Citroen |
+-------+---------+---------+
```

As you can see there are some models in table whose brand is not listed as separate record. I need to include those in my result also (and I am not allowed to add new records to table, so I can not add `brand | Citroen | null` row). My try was to first get all the entries from table and then in `foreach` loop I would filter only values of `brand` type. For each brand, once it is added to table, I would delete that record from `Collection` but also delete all it's children. That way the only records left in `$entries` would be those of type `model` which do not have "parent" record:

```
function filter() {
   $entries = Car::get();
   $result = [];
   foreach($entries as $entry) {
      if($entry->type == 'brand') {
         $result[] = $entry->name;
         //delete $entry and all $entry->models from $entries
      }
   }
   foreach($entries as $entry) {
      $result[] = $entry->brand;
   }   
   return $result;
}
```

Is it possible to remove more then one element of collection, at once?

Here is the relationship between `brand` and `model`:

```
class Car {
   public function models() {
      return $this->hasMany(Car::class, 'brand', 'brand')->where('type', 'model');
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**

This is just simplified version of my real code. So as a result, I do not have array of strings, but array of objects and I can not add duplicate values and then use `array_uniqe`. I am actually filling `$result` array with whole rows, cause I need to use it on front end later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understand your requirement exactly. However from what I understand you want to filter the collection fetched from the database such that only where type is model records are left in the collection.

```php
$results = [];

$entries = Car::get()
    ->reject(function($car) {
        return $car->type === 'model';
    })->values()->all();
```

Let me know if my understanding is correct.

Comment: My question is confusing, sorry about that. I know that I can retrieve data from table this way, but let's say I am not allowed to do it this way. So basically, my question in one sentence would be how can I delete multiple records from collection at once? Or in my case delete all `$entry->models` from `$entries`?

Comment: @nikname Then in that case just use reject on collection it will give a new collection where the rejected items are not present - does it serve your purpose?

Comment: I have never used `reject()` before. This could just be the right solution. Thanks, I'm reading about it now

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-reject for reference

Answer (score 0):

I'd do something like the following:

1. Query the list of parent brands
2. Query the list of models that doens't have a parent included in the previous result

So, something like this:

```
$brandsToExclude = Car::where('type', 'brand')->pluck('name')->all();
$modelsWithoutRegisteredParent = Car::whereNotIn('brand', $brandsToExclude)->get();
```

This way has the advantage that you use the db to perform the operation instead of loading the elements in memory and then filter them.